# Final statement for try clause

Tags: java, soap, proxy, try-catch

I am trying to use Eclipse for creating a client that calls the following web service and it automatically generates the proxy; all that works like a charm:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/eos/validation/services/validation?wsdl

However afterwards I am trying to call the proxy method validateEORI which accepts an array of strings that contains one or more EORI numbers (these are company identifiers used for tax purposes in Europe for example). I only use an array with a single entry though since I want to read them later one by one from a  file.

I have actually 2 questions since there seems to be little in terms of java-related documentation about calling web services:

1. How can I read back the result coming back ? It will normally contain a status code and the address of the company with that EORI number.
2. Why does Eclipse want me to insert a final statement to close off the try clause  ?

Many thanks in advance for any hint you may provide; notably for question 2. Answering question 1 might be too much work; I don't mind if you skip over that one.

### Here is the code I have written:

```
package REX;

import s.dds.eos.ws.eori.*; /* proxy generated automatically from WSDL service description */

public class REX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] EORI;

        EORIValidationProxy proxy = new EORIValidationProxy();
        EORI = new String[1];

        try {
            EORI[0] = "DE1234567890"; /* dummy value */
            proxy.validateEORI(EORI);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `try` without a `catch` or a `finally` is not valid (and utterly useless if it was).

Comment: (1) Does the `validateEORI()` method return anything?  If not, what other methods on that `proxy` object can you use?  This is really a question for the API you're using.  (2) Why do you even have an incomplete `try` block in the first place?  If you're not responding to exceptions, remove the `try` completely.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the catch clause since the error message bugged me that much. Silly mistake. Thanks for the reminder to all of you as several have pointed that out ! As for getting the web service results I need to play around a little more then. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I read back the result coming back ? It will normally contain a status code and the address of the company with that EORI number.

That depends on the webservice and the implementation of the proxy you're using but I'd guess something like `Status s = proxy.validateEORI(EORI);`

> Why does Eclipse want me to insert a final statement to close off the try clause ?

That's because any try-block needs at least one catch-block or a finally-block. Think about what the try-block would mean without that information: "try this" (what would be the difference to "do this", i.e. the statements without the surrounding try-block, here? - there wouldn't be any) ;)

On the other try-catch hand means "try this and if it fails do that" while try-finally basically means "try this and afterwards do that, regardless of the first thing worked or not".